# Outlook 2010 - Sending emails twice

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When one of our user's email from Outlook 2010 (any workstation), it duplicates the sent item and the recipient receives it twice.

The 1st email sends fine with all of the content, but the second only keeps the subject line and has no content in the body of the email.

The sent items appear twice in the users Sent Items folder. I have tested sending using the Outlook WebApp and it doesn't duplicate the email. The user has no client rules setup either.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Extra information: Connected to Exchange 2010 SP1 using SMTP

Answer (score 3):

I have a single customer with the same behaviors,  The mailbox is an Exchange 2010 mailbox and the client software is Outlook 2010.  We found that the user has sync'ed the mailbox to android tablet and iPhone.  When the customer used either the tablet, iPhone or OWA to send emails, there was no duplication.  We turned off both devices and the duplicate messages stopped sending.  After about 3 weeks the problem reappeared.  Turning off the devices for a short time resolved the issue again.  There are no rules in the mailbox, hidden or otherwise.  Creating a new profile does not fix.

Answer (score 0):

**This user's outlook profile may be corrupt.**

1. Locate and rename the Outlook Profile (rename the *.OST file to *.OLD)

   In Windows XP it is located in 
    `c:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook`

   In Windows 7 and Vista it is found in 
   `c:\users\<username>\Appdata\Local\Microsoft\Outlook`
2. [Create a new outlook profile and email account](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829918).

Answer (score 0):

**You may have hidden or stale rules afflicting that mailbox**

One of these methods (easy->hard) should work

- Open an administrator command prompt and run `OUTLOOK.EXE  /cleanrules /cleanserverrules` ([link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/command-line-switches-HP001003110.aspx))
- Run from the Exchange Shell `Get-InboxRule -Mailbox "Joe@Contoso.com" | Remove-InboxRule` ([link](http://powershell.ws/command/Remove-InboxRule/))
- Use Microsoft Exchange Server MAPI Editor (MFCMapi) and purge any items under the profile of type `IPM.Rule.Message` ([link](http://exchangeshare.wordpress.com/2008/04/10/delete-corrupted-hidden-or-stale-rules-from-mailbox-with-mfcmapi/))
  -

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Outlook 2010 on the desktop, Exchange 2010 for the server. Mail sent from Outlook would have a second copy sent out. Our organization uses a disclaimer (applied on the hub transport server with a transport rule). The duplicate sent item would have the same subject line but the body of the message was blank except for the disclaimer. The problem only affected one user, but it affected him even if we configured Outlook on a new computer.

In the end I disabled the disclaimer transport rule and sent a test and this stopped the duplicates. After re-enabling the transport rule the problem has not returned.